# Subdomain with htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I've just setup a subdomain for my site.

My problem is:
when I go to http://xyz.site.com I didn't see anything. Only "The link appears to be broken".
But when I go to http://xyz.site.com/index.html all it works fine.

The problem is in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

If I comment the RewriteRule it works correctly.

How can I fix the htaccess? Maybe with a RewriteCond?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will set a default page in .htaccess if I were you.

DirectoryIndex index.html